# Firebase Cloud functions callback

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

The task is to upload photo of post-model to Firebase storage, convert this photo to thumbnail with Firebase Cloud functions, then apply result of thumbnailRef.getDownloadURL() to post-model. Everything is okay but when I call thumbnailRef.getDownloadURL() it looks like there is no tumb in the storage.

Small code is:

```
storageRef.child(photoName).put(photoData)
  .then(() => {
    storageRef.child(thumbName).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
      // No url here but I need to apply
      model.setPhoto(url)
    })
  })
```

So what's the approach to do that? Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't look like Cloud Functions code.  Is this web client code?  What happens if you log the value of `url` in your callback?

Comment: Yes, this is client's code. Code on the server: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/0f11ca96a7e66f8eaf3d564c392d09c100648ee3/quickstarts/thumbnails/functions/index.js

getDownloadURL() fires error "There is no file `thumbName`". It looks like there is no thumb when put() method returns promise.

Comment: It seems to me that you're not waiting for the server side to finish its work.  It's not synchronous, nor it it instantaneous.  If you want the client to know when the thumbnail is done, you're going to need a channel of communication with the server, either through some known location in a database that you can listen to, or simply make the call HTTP and deliver the image to it directly.

Comment: True. And I'm asking about common approach (if it exists), coz of I do not want to fall to sockets. Another solution is: after creating thumb update record in firestore, I think it's possible.